# how to align and image to left and its description to right in bootsrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get the image to left side and its description to right side and its Heading on the top of both in the code I am mentioning below.
class="panel-body pull-left " did not give me the expected result

@foreach($events as $index => $value)

```
                        <a href="#" >
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="panel pull-left">
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            <li><span class="text-left"><h4 class="panel-title pull-left">{{$events[$index]}}</h4></span></li>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="container">

                                            <img class="panel-title pull-left" src="/image/sample.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre" width="100" height="100" >
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="panel-body pull-left">
                                            <li><h6>{{$description[$index]}}</h6></li>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </a>
                    {{--echo $events[$index].$description[$index];--}}
                    @endforeach
```

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=JslSpkNc2f

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved that in my project used bootstrap's grid for that

```
div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="img">
          <img src="images/trust.png">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="para1">
          <h3>Need to be sincere</h3>
          <p>These personality types embrace rationality and impartiality, excelling in intellectual debates and scientific or technological fields. They are fiercely independent, open-minded, strong-willed and imaginative.
          Diplomats focus on empathy and cooperation, shining in diplomacy and counselling. People belonging to this type group are cooperative and imaginative, often playing the role of harmonizers in their workplace or social circles.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code. Both the pull-left elements should be siblings. You can use like this,

```
<img class="panel-title pull-left" src="image/sample.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre" width="100" height="100" ><div class="panel-body pull-left"><li><h6>Hello World</h6></li></div>
```

And this is just a suggestion. Why are you giving li as a child of div? li should be a child of ul.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make it a media object like this:

```
@foreach($events as $index => $value)
<a href="#" >
    <h4 class="media-heading">{{$events[$index]}}</h4>
        <div class="media">
             <div class="media-left">
                  <img class="media-object" src="/image/sample.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="100px">
             </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h6>{{$description[$index]}}</h6>  
            </div>
        </div>
</a>
```

{{--echo $events[$index].$description[$index];--}}
@endforeach